# I fetch data from podio CRM using PHP

Tags: php, podio

I fetch data from podio CRM using PHP language and I fetch data for each element via its id as it is found in this function:

```
public function getContacts($item_id) {

    $this->contactAuth();

    $item = \PodioItem::get_by_app_item_id($podio_contact_app_id,$item_id);
      return $item;
}
```

For example we have the 'Status' we show it like this:

```
$status = $item->fields[6]->values;
```

Not all elements get it right though it is the same function.

Sometimes :

```
$status = $item->fields[6]->values;
```

and sometimes :

```
$status = $item->fields[8]->values;
```

Can we know what caused the problem?

Comment: Podio will only rerun fields which have values. So, if you don't have value for a field in an item, you won't get it in the response. So best way is to get value using the id of the field.

Comment: I used this function and it did not work : PodioItem::get_basic_by_field( $item_id, $field_id );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some fields are empty they will not be presented in the `PodioItem` object, that is why the position of a particular field in the array may vary (like a Status field in your example).

So instead of using a field index (which may vary), you should get the value from a field by field's **External ID** (a human readable name like 'title', 'status' etc) or **Field ID** (a numeric code):

```
$item->fields['title']->values        // 'title' is an External ID
$item->fields->get(123456789)->values // 123456789 is a Field ID
```

To know what External ID and Field ID are for a particular field you can list all fields like this:

```
// Iterate over the field collection
foreach ($item->fields as $field) {
  // You can now work on each individual field object:
  print "This field has the id: ".$field->field_id;
  print "This field has the external_id: ".$field->external_id;
}
```

Or you can see developer's info on all fields right in Podio in **App menu → Developer**

[image]

And anyways, check the Podio PHP wrapper documentation at https://podio-community.github.io/podio-php/items/ it is pretty useful:)